# C# and C++, out parameter does not return anything in a method

Tags: c#, c++

I need help with a method, it is a method imported from a dll, the method is in C++ and it is the following:

```
DECLSPEC int WINAPI I15693_Inventorys(HID_DEVICE device, BYTE *pData, BYTE *pLen);
```

The correct translation to C# is this (Provided by the manufacturer):

```
public static extern int I15693_Inventorys(IntPtr device, byte[] pData, ref byte pLen);
```

The problem is that the method has 2 OUT parameters (The pData and pLen ones), one of which has a ref and the other does not, I need the value of the second parameter's out but I can't get it, does not return anything, if I modify the method and add a ref for that parameter the program crashes, any ideas? This is my code:

```
byte[] chip = Array.Empty<byte>();
byte longitud = 0;
_ = RFIDReader.Sys_SetAntenna(g_hDevice, 0);
_ = RFIDReader.Sys_InitType(g_hDevice, 1);
_ = RFIDReader.Sys_SetAntenna(g_hDevice, 1);
int resultado = RFIDReader.I15693_Inventorys(g_hDevice, chip, ref longitud);
```

Oh, and the method returns me an error code of 0, which executes correctly, but without returning anything from the second parameter. Also say that the method in c++ seems that both parameters have a pointer, so in its translation both should have a ref, right?

EDIT:

[image: Documentation of the method]

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/passing-arrays-as-arguments). It should answer your question.

Comment: You're supposed to pass a non-empty array along with its size. The function replaces the array's contents and returns in `pLen` how many elements were overwritten. (The C++ interface has an *in* `BYTE*` and an *in/out* `BYTE`, implemented as a `BYTE*`.)

Comment: @molbdnilo You were right, I did not have to send it empty, I thought It would add it instead of overwriting it, although it does not return what it should return, but that is another issue that I can solve with documentation, or so I hope

Comment: @molbdnilo Completely solved, thanks man, I have already converted the result into what I wanted, everything working fine

Answer (score -1):

You should pin the value for handling in unmanaged memory.

```
byte longitud = 0;
GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(longitud, GCHandleType.Pinned);

// Call your function
int resultado = RFIDReader.I15693_Inventorys(g_hDevice, chip, ref longitud);

gch.Free();
```